# start camera rotation from specific point in three js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a panoramic image loaded in threejs but it starts camera rotation from the logic below which is default in threejs

```
if ( isUserInteracting === false ) {

    lon += 0.1;
}

lat = Math.max( - 85, Math.min( 85, lat ) );
phi = THREE.Math.degToRad( 90 - lat );
theta = THREE.Math.degToRad( lon );

camera.target.x = 100 * Math.sin( phi ) * Math.cos( theta );
camera.target.y = 100 * Math.cos( phi );
camera.target.z = 100 * Math.sin( phi ) * Math.sin( theta );
```

What I want to do is place the camera at a specific point which I am able to place using

```
camera.lookAt( -56.86954186163314,  0,  -71.49481268065709 );
```

Now i want to start normal camera rotation from the above lookAt point. What I am currently doing is

```
camera.lookAt( -56.86954186163314 + camera.target.x,  0,  -71.49481268065709 + camera.target.z);
```

Which is wrong I think.. PS (I am very weak in geometry, sin, cos).. Can any 1 please help me with this?? PS(I dont want to change `camera.target.y` It should be 0).. Thanks in advance..

Comment: @TheJim01 any idea??

Comment: The camera position, often called the Transform, which is (x, y, z) LOCATION and (x, y, z) ROTATION are two different things.  You are putting the location `+ camera.target.x` into the rotation oriented `lookAt()` call.  I think you should try that `camera.target.x` into the camera's location, not it's look at rotation.

Comment: @jmb.mage basically I am capturing that static point by using camera.target.x, camera.target.y, camera.target.z and place the camera at the same place using camera.lookAt() and start rotation from there.(My image is normal 360 panorama). I just want the camera to do normal rotation like the default three js code from my static point

Comment: The reason i captured camera.target is because the default three js code passes camera.target in `camera.lookAt(camera.target)` call

Comment: I want normal camera rotation like here https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_panorama_equirectangular.html  but starting from my static point

Comment: What do you mean when you say "Now i want to start normal camera rotation from the above lookAt"?  Are you rotating the camera around the camera's axis or are you rotating the camera at a set distance from the object's axis?

Comment: I think rotating the camera around camera's axis.. i.e at the same place.. just turn around the camera to look at the picture 360 degrees.. like turning around your neck by standing at 1 place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is best looked at from the perspective of vectors.

Take your `lookAt` position: that's a vector. You can make that vector spin around an axis using [`Vector3.applyAxisAngle`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/math/Vector3.applyAxisAngle). As you update the vector, make your camera look at it.

For your example, you want the camera to look at `-56.86954186163314,  0,  -71.49481268065709`, and then spin 360° about the Y-axis (the camera position doesn't change, and the `lookAt` target doesn't change its Y value).

```
var lookVector = new THREE.Vector3();

// later...
lookVector.set(x, y, z); // -56.86954186163314,  0,  -71.49481268065709

// down with your render function...
var axis = new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0);

function render(){
    lookVector.applyAxisAngle(axis, 0.001); // or some other theta
    camera.lookAt(lookVector);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

You'll need to track when your thetas add up to 360°, and perform logic to stop the rotation, but I'll leave that as an exercise for you.

Comment: hey @TheJim01 it worked.. I am able to make the camera to look at the desired point and start the rotation but the rotation is happening from right to left.. which is not normal.. I want it from left to right.. I have no clue why that is happening.. I have removed the default three js logic-> `lat = Math.max( - 85, Math.min( 85, lat ) );
phi = THREE.Math.degToRad( 90 - lat );
theta = THREE.Math.degToRad( lon );

camera.target.x = 100 * Math.sin( phi ) * Math.cos( theta );
camera.target.y = 100 * Math.cos( phi );
camera.target.z = 100 * Math.sin( phi ) * Math.sin( theta );`

Comment: Change the `theta` to a negative number.

Comment: Thanksss a lotttttt.. you are great.. got this working after strugling for lot of days.. Works perfectly..  If you remember i had posted 1 more question saying I have start and end point.. so starting camera rotation from the start point is done.. now I want to detetct as soon as camera lookat vector reaches or exceeds a specific point(end point).. Any idea how to get that?

Comment: Look at it from the perspective of a counter, and track how many times you've rotated the camera by `theta`. If you require a more detailed explanation, please create a new question.